# Is it possible to load a webform that is using a specific custom handler?

Tags: webforms

I have a custom handler for one of our webforms, it may be re-used for other webforms. It integrates with a 3rd party API and sends the response back to Drupal.
I have to save the submissions to handle the response.
I`m wondering if its possible to load all webforms which are using this custom handler?

My goal is delete submissions of those webforms when they are older than a certain time.

Comment: Webform 5/6 supports the automatic purging of submissions. see /admin/structure/webform/manage/{webform_id}/settings/submissions

Answer (score 2):

You can use the next code:

```
$webforms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->loadMultiple();
  foreach ($webforms as $webform) {
    foreach ($webform->getHandlers() as $handler) {
      if ($handler->getPluginId() == 'your_custom_handler') {
        // do your logic.
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```